# How to parallel run independent loops on Tensorflow in GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, parallels, logistics

I want to implement the algorithm to reconstruct Restricted Boltzmann Machines via simulation. The M is number of visible variables and N is number of hidden variables. In order to parallel run on GPU, I want to write it on tensorflow using python first.

1. In my main function RBMIC(), I need to run M independent logistics regression with L1 penalty and update my weight and bias matrices:(w and b) and then use them later to impute the value of hidden variables. So I write an independent for loop. I wonder does tensorflow could identify the independent for loops and run it efficiently (each core with one iteration) on GPU?
2. The code is also very slow especially for running logistics regression since it need to run epochs=1000 times to minimize the loss function. But I find it is very fast if I use sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression. Why is it a huge difference? But in order to use GPU, I still want to use tensorflow to write logistics regression. Could anyone give me some advice on how to write it more efficiently?
3. When I writing logistics regression function: LogisticsReg(), I need to get the weight and bias and I also need them to keep as tensorflow variables for my further calculation. But according to my function:LogisticsReg(), it returns non-tensor variable after sess.run(). So I transform them again into tensor-variables. Does this part be reasonable? Or is there any efficient way to keep it in tensor variable and then can be used to update the weight and bias matrices (w and b)? Thank you for your suggestions!

I am very new to tensorflow and python. Sorry for interruption and Thank you for your time!!

```html
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


n = 200
M = 4
N = 2
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
beta = 0.001
lr=0.05
epochs = 1000
Maxepochs = 10
iteration = 100


visible = np.array([[1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1]])
vis = np.tile(visible,50).reshape(n,M)
vis = tf.cast(vis, tf.float32)
err_hat = np.zeros([iteration])


def Bionimal(x):
    sample = tf.where(tf.random_uniform(shape=x.shape) - x < 0,
                      tf.ones(shape=x.shape), tf.zeros(shape=x.shape))
    return sample

def LogisticsReg(X, Y, wj, bj, beta, lr, epochs):
    logitj = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, wj), bj)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y, logits=logitj))
    l1_regularizer = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(wj))
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss + beta * l1_regularizer)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss, var_list=[wj, bj])
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        for k in range(epochs):  # train the model n_epochs times
            _, bf, wf = sess.run([optimizer, bj, wj])
    # bf = tf.Variable(bf,name="bf")
    # wf = tf.Variable(wf,name="wf")
    return [bf, wf]

def UpdateC(wi, hi, c_opt, Maxepochs):
    ph = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(vis, tf.transpose(wi)), c_opt))
    lik = tf.add(tf.multiply(hi, tf.log(ph)), tf.multiply((1. - hi), tf.log(1. - ph)))
    loss2 = -tf.reduce_sum(lik)
    optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss2, var_to_bounds={c_opt: (-1,1)},options={'maxiter': Maxepochs}, var_list=[c_opt])
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        optimizer.minimize(sess)
        return sess.run(c_opt)



# initial
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(N, M), stddev=0.1), name="weights")
c = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(1, N), stddev=0.1), name="hbias")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(1, M), stddev=0.1), name="vbias")


def RBMIC(w,c,vis):
    # calculate hidden variables
    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(vis, tf.transpose(w)), tf.tile(c, [n, 1]))
    prob = tf.sigmoid(logits)
    hids = Bionimal(prob)
    # estimate bias, weight by logistics regression with l1 penalty and also bias c for visible variables.
    bs = np.zeros([1, M])
    ws = np.zeros([N, M])
    X = hids
    for j in range(M):
        Y = tf.reshape(vis[:, j], [n, 1])
        wj = tf.Variable(tf.reshape(w[:, j], [N, 1]), name="wj")
        bj = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[1, 1], stddev=0.1), name="bj")
        bf, wf = LogisticsReg(X, Y, wj, bj, beta, lr, epochs)
        bs[0, j] = bf
        ws[:, [j]] = wf
    b = tf.cast(tf.Variable(bs, name="vbias"), tf.float32)
    w = tf.cast(tf.Variable(ws, name="weights"), tf.float32)
    cs = np.zeros([1, N])
    for i in range(N):
        wi = tf.reshape(w[i, :], [1, M])
        hi = tf.reshape(hids[:, i], [n, 1])
        c_opt = tf.Variable(c[0, i], name="c_opt")
        cs[0, i] = UpdateC(wi, hi, c_opt, Maxepochs)
    c = tf.cast(tf.Variable(cs, name="hbias"), tf.float32)
    # evaluate performance
    vis_pred = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(hids, w), tf.tile(b, [n, 1])))
    err = tf.reduce_sum((vis_pred - vis) ** 2)
    return err



for step in range(iteration):  # train the model iteration times
        err = RBMIC(w,c,vis)
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess = tf.Session()
        sess.run(init)
        print 'reconstruct at step %d = \n' % (step)
        print sess.run(err)
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title of your post, the control flow construct [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) supports parallel execution of iterations (exposed via the keyword argument `parallel_iterations`).

With respect to your second and third questions, you likely don't want to  create multiple sessions. If you use a single session, you won't have to transform your tensors into variables, for example. I strongly encourage you to consult the tutorials and documentation for more information about the semantics of TensorFlow [graphs and sessions](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs).